# PHP preg_match regular expression for find date in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to make system that can detect date in some string, here is the code :

```
$string = "02/04/16   10:08:42";
$pattern = "/\<(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\.- \/\.- \d{2}\>/";
$found = preg_match($pattern, $string);
            if ($found) {
                echo ('The pattern matches the string');
            } else {
                echo ('No match');
            }
```

The result i found is "No Match", i don't think that i used correct regex for the pattern. Can somebody tell me what i must to do to fix this code

Comment: What date format are you trying to match ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy, are my pattern wrong ?

Comment: You say `dd/mm/yyyy` but your year is 2 digit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove all gibberish from the pattern. This is the part you'll need to work on:

```
(/0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]/)
```

(As you said, you need the date only, not the datetime).

The main problem with the pattern, that you are using the logical **OR** operators (`|`) at the delimiters. If the delimiters are slashes, then you need to replace the tube characters with escaped slashes (`/`). Note that you need to escape them, because the parser will not take them as control characters. Like this: `\/`.

Now, you need to solve some logical tasks here, to match the numbers correctly and you're good to go.
(I'm not gonna solve the homework for you `:)` )

These articles will help you to solve the problem tough:

- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- [Repetition opetors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- [Special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)
- [Pipe character (alternation operator)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say you are looking for yyyy, but the example says yy.
I made a code for yy because that is what you gave us, you can easily change the 2 to a 4 and it's for yyyy.

```
preg_match("/((0|1|2|3)[0-9])\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/", $string, $output_array);
Echo $output_array[1]; // date
```

Edit:

If you use this pattern it will match the time too, thus make it harder to match wrong.
((0|1|2|3)[0-9])/\d{2}/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fjP

Edit2:

Also, you can skip one line of code.
You first preg_match to $found and then do an if $found.
This works too:

```
If(preg_match($pattern, $string, $found))}{
    Echo $found[1];
}Else{
    Echo "nothing found";
}
```

With pattern and string as refered to above.
As you can see the found variable is in the preg_match as the output, thus if there is a match the if will be true.